# regular expression match match until special text is found

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have this text:

```
Second reply. #2

Met vriendelijke groet,
{sender name}

{company details}

On 25-02-15 14:38, {email name} wrote:
> [Ticket ID: 54e70396110971424425] Re: 54e70396110,678567.971424425
>
> ##- Please type your reply above this line -##
>
> Your request (54e70396110971424425) has been deemed solved. To reopen, 
> please reply to this email or login on {name} to reply.
>
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> Feb 25, 14:38
>
> Dear Test user,
>
> First reply. #1
>
>
> {name}
> {company details}
>
```

I need a regex to match only this:

```
Second reply. #2

Met vriendelijke groet,
{sender name}

{company details}
```

And stops matching when this is found:

```
On 25-02-15 14:38, {email name} wrote:
```

Or when this is found:

```
##- Please type your reply above this line -##
```

I have not enough knowledge of regular expressions myself, so I'm hoping someone can help me with this one.
This text is received by e-mail, so the most important thing for me is to match this `##- Please type your reply above this line -##`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this:

```
$re = "/^(.*?)(?=On\\s+\\d{2}\\-\\d+\\-\\d+|\\#{2}\\-.*?\\-\\#{2})/s"; 
$str = "YOUR_INPUT_STRING"; 

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
```

See [Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/cG6xT8/1).

If the `>` before `##-` should not be matched, use `^`:

```
$re = "/^(.*?)(?=On\\s+\\d{2}\\-\\d+\\-\\d+|\^\s*\\#{2}\\-.*?\\-\\#{2})/s";
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand the descriptions from regex101.com, but I would never have been able to come up with this myself.

Comment: I assumed that you need to capture everything from the beginning till the date (that is always in dd-MM-yyyy-like format). In case a different locale is used, you might need to trim the regex pattern a bit. Also, the trick here is to use the `/s` modifier to match multiline text.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
preg_match('#^(.*)\#\#- Please type your reply#s', $string, $matches);
```

Your result should be found in `$matches[1]`.